# What is the difference between is losing and has been losing?

Tags: tense

I would like to know the difference between these to sentences.

1. My company is losing money this year.
2. My company has been losing money this year.

Answer (score 2):

I am a native speaker, so my grammar might not be exactly right, but this is what these sentences mean to me.

1 is the present continuous - the present it refers to is 'this year', as opposed to last year. It says that the company *at present* is losing money.

2 is [present perfect continuous](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfectcontinuous.html) and it refers to the state of the company in the recent past. The link says it is used to emphasise duration, which agrees with my experience. 'This year' refers to a period of time up to this moment. During that time, the company was losing money.

I think the important distinction is that in 1, 'this year' refers to a *moment* in time, and in 2, 'this year' refers to a *period* of time.

The following examples may help:

Describing a *period of time*

> **CORRECT:** The company has been losing money for three years.
>
> **INCORRECT:** The company is losing money for three years.

Describing a *moment in time*

> **CORRECT:** The company is losing money at the moment.
>
> **INCORRECT:** The company has been losing money at the moment.